# Custom Post Type: Get most recent permalink

Tags: permalinks, custom-post-types

Stupid question, I bet: I'm doing a website for an artist where I have a custom post type of "Painting". How do I get the permalink of the one added most recently?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple function that will return the Permalink of the last painting post:

```
function Get_most_recent_permalink(){
    global $post;
    $tmp_post = $post;
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => 1,
        'offset'          => 0,
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'post_type'       => 'Painting',
        'post_status'     => 'publish' );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    $permalink = get_permalink($myposts[0]->ID);
    $post = $tmp_post;
    return $permalink;
}
```

so once you paste that function in your theme's functions.php file you can just call it whenever you want:

```
<a href="<?php echo Get_most_recent_permalink(); ?>">last painting</a>
```

Comment: Well, thanks for trying but not working as given. Here's the thing: I'm using in an iframe and it keeps giving me (when I use the above code) the PARENT url in the place where I want the most recent painting. That is, the URL in the address field, the current URL. Which is bound to be a problem as it will have itself inside itself, etc.

Comment: what??? this function works in one manner, create a pastebin of your code or update the question with it so I'll get a better look and understanding.

Comment: $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID); should be $permalink = get_permalink($myposts[0]->ID);  This is why user3960 was getting the currentURL cause the latest URL is the one he working on and publishing.  $myposts is the filter posts based on the args. I'll update the reply with this correction.

Comment: @RedWolves not true! since you use `setup_postdata($myposts[0]);` one line above it which sets the `$post` object.

Comment: Well it's not doing what you expect!  It doesn't work as you have it.

Comment: I agree this function works like a charme! I just didn't recognize I can't use it within a prefined menu via register_nav_menus. Any ideas how to fix that?