# How do I get Link for Oldest Custom Post Type (dynamically)

Tags: custom-post-types

Anyone know how I could take the below script that was answered for retrieving the latest permalink for a Custom Post Type and flip it to get the oldest post instead?

[This is the link for retrieving custom post type latest post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12143/custom-post-type-get-most-recent-permalink)

Answer (score 2):

Simply change order parameter from `DESC` to `ASC`:

```
function Get_First_permalink(){
    global $post;
    $tmp_post = $post;
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => 1,
        'offset'          => 0,
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'post_type'       => 'POST_TYPE_NAME',
        'post_status'     => 'publish' );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    setup_postdata($myposts[0]);
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $post = $tmp_post;
    return $permalink;
}
```

so once you paste that function in your theme's functions.php  and you have changed  `POST_TYPE_NAME`  to your post type name ,you can just call it whenever you want:

```
<a href="<?php echo Get_First_permalink(); ?>">First Post</a>
```

Comment: I know this is an old question/answer. But this worked for me by changing `get_permalink($post->ID);` to `get_permalink($myposts[0]->ID);`. Maybe this will help someone else too.